# context.document.saved property is prematurely updated even before the document is saved to SharePoint

Tags: office-js

I have a query reg context.document.saved   property
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document?product=word

Repro steps - 
Step 1) use the snippet here to create a Word task pane addin -

```
 function getDataFromSelection() {
        Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

                    Word.run(function (context) {

                        var thisDocument = context.document;

                        // Queue a commmand to load the document save state (on the saved property).
                        context.load(thisDocument, 'saved');

                        return context.sync().then(function () {


                            app.showNotification('The saved state right now is:', '"' + thisDocument.saved + '"'); 

                        });
                    })

                } else {

                  //  do nothing
                }
            }
        );
```

step 2 - Have a docx file hosted on any SP site
Step 3 - Click on it and open it in Word client app (Word 2016)
Step 4 - Side Load your add-in onto Word (using https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)
Step 5 - your addin should load fine 
Step 6 - Make some change in the document, when you click the button the saved property says false
Step 7 - Now hit the Save button in Word, and IMMEDIATELY click on the addin button  again to check the saved property. You will see the addin saved property becomes TRUE even before the document is uploaded to SharePoint

Expectations - the saved property should be true once the document is actually saved to SP.

Current behaviour - I feel the saved property being set to true immediately is incorrect.

If the above is by design, is there any better way to know that the document is successfully saved, currently we were relying on the saved property.

Comment: thanks for reporting this. Sounds like a bug, but  we are investigating this issue and will answer as soon as we have something to share. This might be a big issue, specially on very large documents.

Comment: True Juan - this is impacting our customers, especially for large documents. I am happy to see your acknowledgement and look forward to more response from your end.

Comment: Hello it will be great if you can please share the build where you are experiencing this. thanks.

Comment: Quick update.. we are able to repro this behavior. We are investigating this.

Comment: Thanks Juan - Any further updates or tentative fix timelines, if possible?    PS - I am really happy to get constant updates from Microsoft side.

Comment: I want to also let you know that VBA property "Document.Saved" also shows this behaviour. Does that help understanding the behaviour ?

Comment: Hello, yes we also observed that the VBA property behaves in the same way, so this might be a by design issue. We are still investigating and will let you know if we will fix and by when it will be available for you to try. thanks!

Comment: Hi Juan - Thanks! Look forward to more updates on a possible fix, if possible.

Comment: Hello! the team is actively working on this. Will update as soon as more details are available. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Juan! Any further news on this issue?

Comment: Hello! so far what we've seen is that this is a by design issue, Can you share more details about your scenario? I would like to understand in what conditions is critical to have this check. Your sample does not make too much sense (checking the property after making a selection?) I wonder what links the value of the property in the context of your end to end scenario.

Comment: For large documents, we rely on this property to determine when the document is saved, based on that we trigger the next steps. Since this property gives erroneous indication, our next step fails too.

Comment: Hello, upon further investigation turns out that the flag is reporting the state of the document accurately, at least from the sense of holding a local copy saved. what happens when a document is saved to one drive is that its first locally saved, then uploaded. The small delay you see happens on uploading changes. Right now there is no event for uploading, but we are trying to see if we could have the addition of a new property for this. thanks!

Comment: sure, thanks for update and consideration. Would you have any rough ETA on when this feedback may be incorporated, if possible.

Comment: No we don't have any ETA at this point, but i think you should be minimally impacted by this issue.

Comment: Thanks Juan - For large files, we have some impact - request your kind consideration on this.

Comment: Hi @user5501201, have you got any solution. we are facing same issue.

Comment: @JuanBalmori - do you have any update on this issue?

Comment: I have reported the issue on github -> https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2833